# Создание чата и какой набор технологий взять?

Tags: java, spring

Всем привет. Есть небольшая задачка на работе. Все очень вроде как просто. Надо написать небольшой чатик, в котором один человек сможет писать другому, не путать с групповым. То что тут надо писать на веб сокетах это факт. Но в остальном я не знаю что использовать и по архитектуре смутно понимаю что к чему, ибо это не обычные круды писать.

Итак вопросы по теме:

- Какие технологии применяются в таких задачах, и дадут хороший профит
  и производительность?
- Какую лучше всего бд выбрать, для сохранения истории сообщений?
- Использовать ли websphere или еще что-то для этого?
- Может есть еще нюанс в этой задаче который вы можете знать?
- Мб кто-то подскажет по архитектуре?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Добрый совет, возьмите готовое :) это безусловно зря потраченное время, позднее, вы поймёте что нужен тот или иной функционал, что выльется в объемный клиент-серверный проект.. Из рекомендаций, возьмите любой клиент IRC например, настройте канал как приватный, и останется только вбивать доступ пользователям. Так-же легко поднимается серверная часть на собственном сервере, если есть строгие рамки к секретности.

Comment: Почему не CRUD? Вполне себе можно и с ним писать. А вообще, попробуйте узнать, что конкретно вы должны делать и почему было решено писать подобное приложение самостоятельно. Скорее всего вы не понимаете, что заказчик хочет увидеть на выходе, соответственно, не можете и нам это сказать. А без этого, давать рекомендации относительно ваших вопросов - это тыкать пальцем в небо, в надежде, что что-то из этого получится